# array of document.getElementById() which is not working to change the borderColor of array of textboxes

Tags: javascript, html

Am having array of `Quantity` textbox and i made textbox border color to red with the value is not present in the textbox. But if it a single element am able to achieve my requirement (validation). But how i can do with the array of elements (array of getElementById()).

Please find my below code which am trying. Its an ReactJS application with MongoDB.

```
var item = this.state.item;
var lines = item.order_items;
for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
document.getElementById(lines[i].quantity).value ?  document.getElementById(lines[i].quantity).style.borderColor = "" :  document.getElementById(lines[i].quantity).style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: what is `lines`? what is `i`? if that's the code you're trying, it is far from "complete"

Comment: `lines` is an array of `order_items` table. which containing array of elements and `Quantity` is one among the elements